# Making new dataframe using information from another datafram

Tags: python, numpy

I had a parameter file that contains information of each time step and in each time step, there is the information of 1000 observation samples in 6 features.
The parameter file is like bellow:

```
 0   10.000000   0.100000   0.010000   
 1    9.999620   0.099991   0.010000   
 2    9.997776   0.099950   0.009998   
 3    9.988489   0.099739   0.009988   
 4    9.942557   0.098700   0.009943   
 5    9.760542   0.094644   0.009761   
 6    9.407192   0.086875   0.009407   
 7    9.103566   0.080466   0.009104   
 8    8.933587   0.076973   0.008934   
 9    9.269883   0.083504   0.009270
```

The first columns is time step counter, I want to open each time step file and add these 4 columns in each time step file to make it 10 columns for each row. The code that I have written is below but it does not work since there is a problem of broadcasting. It should be pointed ot, in each time-step file, the added columns are reppeated for all rows.

```
import numpy as np

lines = open("parameters.csv").readlines() # Reading the parameters file
for line in lines: # Processing the parameters file line by line
    s = line.strip().split() # Spliting a line of parameters file
    rows = open("configuration_"+s[0]+".txt").readlines() # Opening the corresponding configuration file
    matrice = np.zeros((len(rows), 10)) 
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        print(row.strip().split())
        matrice[i] = np.asarray(row.strip().split())
    matrice = matrice[:,1:4]
    for i in range(4,1,-1):
        temp = np.ones((len(rows), 1)) * float(s[i])
        matrice = np.concatenate((temp,matrice), axis=1)
    np.savetxt("output/configuration_"+s[0]+".txt", matrice, delimiter="\t", fmt='%1.8f')
```

the error that I have gotten is this:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-80d1d98bc842> in <module>
      8    # print(np.shape(matrice))
      9     for i, row in enumerate(rows):
---> 10         matrice[i] = np.asarray(row.strip().split())
     11 
     12         matrice = matrice[:,1:4]

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6) into shape (10)```
````

Comment: A question and detailed error description is missing in your post

Comment: @YannickFunk I added the aforementioned error. Thanks

Comment: The Error is exactly telling you whats wrong, you are trying to assign an array of shape 6 to an array of shape 10

Comment: @YannickFunk The existing file has 6 columns and I want to increase by 4 to become 10. I do not know how to increase?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the data directly into a numpy array using [np.loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), then use [np.tile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) to repeat the four columns of parameters for the equivalent number of rows of the configuration file loaded into `config` variable. After this, apply the same concatenation operation you're already using along the column axis.

```
├── input
│   ├── configuration_0.txt
│   ├── configuration_1.txt
│   ├── configuration_2.txt
│   └── ...
├── parameters.csv
```

```
param = np.loadtxt("parameters.csv")
for i in range(len(param)):
    config = np.loadtxt(f'input/configuration_{i}.txt')
    # repeat params for all rows of configuration file
    rep_param = np.tile(param[i],(len(config),1))
    # concat. 6 columns with 4 params
    new = np.concatenate((config, rep_param), axis=1)
    np.savetxt(f'output/configuration_{i}.txt', new, delimiter="\t", fmt='%1.8f')
```

output/configuration_0.txt

```
0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  10.00000000 0.10000000  0.01000000
0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  10.00000000 0.10000000  0.01000000
0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  10.00000000 0.10000000  0.01000000
...
```

output/configuration_1.txt

```
0.11111111  0.11111111  0.11111111  0.11111111  0.11111111  0.11111111  1.00000000  9.99962000  0.09999100  0.01000000
0.11111111  0.11111111  0.11111111  0.11111111  0.11111111  0.11111111  1.00000000  9.99962000  0.09999100  0.01000000
0.11111111  0.11111111  0.11111111  0.11111111  0.11111111  0.11111111  1.00000000  9.99962000  0.09999100  0.01000000
...
```

output/configuration_2.txt

```
0.22222222  0.22222222  0.22222222  0.22222222  0.22222222  0.22222222  2.00000000  9.99777600  0.09995000  0.00999800
0.22222222  0.22222222  0.22222222  0.22222222  0.22222222  0.22222222  2.00000000  9.99777600  0.09995000  0.00999800
0.22222222  0.22222222  0.22222222  0.22222222  0.22222222  0.22222222  2.00000000  9.99777600  0.09995000  0.00999800
...
```